# How could Shrek's friends arrive so quickly?

Tags: plot-explanation, shrek-2

When Shrek and Fiona travel to "Far Far Away" in *Shrek 2*, the travel scene is portrayed as a very long one, because, well, they do travel "far far away".

Before leaving his swamp, Shrek hands it over to gingerbread man, three piggies, Pinocchio and others to "guard".

Later on, gingerbread man recognizes Shrek when watching "TV" and the whole group is able to help him in a matter of hours. This sounds like a plot hole to me. Or is there any explanation of how they could arrive to help him so quickly?

Comment: Because: cartoon

Comment: Related question on SFF:SE - [How does Shrek's rescue party reach him so fast at the end of Shrek 2?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73133/how-does-shreks-rescue-party-reach-him-so-fast-at-the-end-of-shrek-2)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I asked the film's screenwriter, [David N Weiss](https://twitter.com/DavidNWeiss/status/595010721651433472). He confirmed that they flew to Far Far Away on Dragon.

[image]

---

It might also interest you to know that at that point in the film, Dragon [may have been in the form of a Pegasus](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111603/20774) as a result of the "Happily Ever After Potion".

Comment: I wouldn't call that a straight confirmation as much as he probably not knowing it that well himself (judging from the wording). But well, it's something at least.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - I really don't see any other way to read it.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - The Directors commentary notes that they wanted to show her earlier but struggled with the script because she was a walking (in fact flying) Deus ex machina, able to smash down the gate of the castle or kill the Fairy Godmother with consummate ease.

Comment: You might want to add that into the answer then, it sounds like it adds quite a bit to the whole topic.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - Well, it's the out-of-universe answer to a question that hasn't been asked ("*If everyone got there on Dragon, then why the hell didn't she help Shrek and Donkey storm the castle?*"

Comment: But it seems the question is confused by not having seen the friends arrive on Dragon, while the commentary seems to explain why that wasn't shown. And in addition to that it would support a Twitter quote that to me still sounds a bit like a joke/retcon/inofficial-"um...yeah, sounds good", even if it isn't. But anyway, I've (unfortunately?) already upvoted it anyway and might simply be making an ass of myself for not having seen the movie at all.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - He's not saying "*I guess*" though.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - Go watch it. It's fun and the song/dance number at the end is cinematic gold.

Comment: *"He's not saying "I guess" though."* - Fixed.